# How to add custom companies as ORG entity in inbuilt spacy model "en_core_web_lg"?

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have few companies which are not in current in-built model `en_core_web_lg` of `spacy`.

How to add my new companies in this exiting spacy model `en_core_web_lg`?

I have gone through many blogs but none of them has mentioend how to add custom company names in existing model.

Is there any way to leverage existing model without training totally new model?

For example# https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/training-custom-ner-model-in-spacy/

Comment: Yes. You can do that. Are you looking to add a finite number of predefined companies?

Comment: @raqib - yes, thanks for comment. could you please tell me how?